# On Linux, how do you determine which individual pages are resident?

Tags: linux, memory

How can one determine which individual pages are resident (i.e., committed in RAM)?  On Linux, /proc/pid/smaps gives, for a fixed set of ranges, how many bytes are resident in that range, but this information doesn't tell you what actual ranges of memory are resident.

As for what this is intended to be used for:
I already have data associating allocation ranges with the source line info.  This is useful for finding who is allocating how much.  Given resident memory ranges, I could correlate the data to find who is allocating how much memory that was being kept resident.

Thanks!

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syscall to do this:

```
mincore - determine whether pages are resident in memory

int mincore(void *addr, size_t length, unsigned char *vec);
```

Comment: Gotta love unix syscalls naming convention. If only all their manpages include the rationale behind for their names. I'm guessing that it stands for "memory in core". Can't say the same for ``creat`` though.

Comment: @holygeek: Well, `creat` is just missing the final *e*, not sure who is responsible for that one. Though the why may make a good question for somewhere on SE... Not sure where.

Comment: @derobert Many, many years late, but Ken Thompson is to blame for that particular quirk.